# Open GL - ES 2.0 : Dynamically Changing the color

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

In most of the tutorials in opengl es they create a structure which holds the vertices of the geometry. This structure contains the position and color for each vertex. This vertex information is then sent to the vertex buffer and is then used to render the geometry on the screen. My question is if I want to draw 2 cubes on the screen do I need to create 2 different structures objects or can I get by just creating a single structure and then changing the color dynamically.

This is the definition of my structure

```
struct Vertex{
   float Position[3];
   float Color[4];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use just one instance of the structure, draw it, than change the colors of it and draw it again with another world matrix. Though I don't think that would be very good for performance.

But the best thing to do would be to create two instances of that one structure each one containing different colors, then draw them in differents positions by multiplying a translation matrix to their world matrix.

Comment: I think I understand but I am not sure... Can you provide some sample/ pseudo code? Also after looking a lot on google I came across the concept of vertex arrays. What would be the difference in using vertex arrays as opposed to your approach?